# Duplication in Racket

Tags: recursion, racket

I am having trouble duplicating a symbol. Basically I have a list and I need to surround it with same number of the symbol @ as the number of elements in the list you pass.

For example:

`(display(frontenddupe '@ '((! % % % !)(! % ! % !))))`

and I'm suppose to get the following as an output:

`((@ @ @ @ @)(! % % % !)(! % ! % !)(@ @ @ @ @))`

This is my code that I have so far:

```
(define (frontenddupe s lst)
 (define (duplicate n s)
  (cond`]
    [(zero? n) '()]
    [else (append (list s (duplicate (- n 1) s)))]))

(append (list (list (duplicate (length lst) '@ ))(list s) lst (list (list s)))))
```

I know this is completely wrong, but I am just at a total lost on how to fix it.

Comment: why does the fourth sublist in the expected output contain more parens? `((@ @ @ @ @))`

Comment: @Thankyou That's a mistake on my part. It should be `(@ @ @ @ @))` It is fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a solution without using explicit recursion, just use some of the built-in procedures - like this:

```
(define (frontenddupe s lst)
  (let* ([len (length (first lst))] ; assuming all lists have same length
         [dup (build-list len (λ (n) s))])
    (append (cons dup lst) (list dup))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(frontenddupe '@ '((! % % % !) (! % ! % !)))
=> '((@ @ @ @ @) (! % % % !) (! % ! % !) (@ @ @ @ @))
```

Comment: just using the length of the first sublist? i was afraid to make this same assumption but couldn’t think of any other reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: Yes, I'm making that assumption, I'll make it explicit. There isn't enough information in the question to think otherwise.

Comment: i would prefer `(λ (n) s)` to be `(λ (_) s)`, or is there another racket convention to “ignore” a binding?

Comment: Yes, that's also a good suggestion. But I'd rather see some variable name, in this case `(_)` just looks weird ;)

Comment: I love how Oscar's answers are always something along the lines of "you actually don't have to use recursion; try this instead: *awesome code example goes here*"